# python tkinter button argument

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I'm writing a code to insert data to sqlite in tkinter, but i can't add arguments to a function in Button. When i execute fun_sprowadzdosql it doesn't get the argument. my code:

```
def fun_Wprowadz():
    okno.iconify()
    global Wprowadz
    Wprowadz=Toplevel()
    PrzyciskWprowadz=Button(Wprowadz, text="Wprowadź", width=30, height=2, command=lambda x="tekst": fun_sprowadzdosql(x))
    PrzyciskWprowadz.grid(row=0, column=0)

testowy=str

def fun_sprowadzdosql(str: testowy):
    print(testowy)
```

Comment: I don't see any arguments in your code.

Comment: As it stands, should print `tekst`

Comment: @stovfl yeah. but actually it only prints <class 'str'>

Comment: @Flord: Should read `def fun_sprowadzdosql(testowy :str):` [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/AccurateOffensiveDefinition)

Comment: @stovfl thank you. I understand now.